# How to build shared library from spatialite as static library NDK

Tags: spatialite, android, compile

I want to build a shared library for android to link with JNI,
all libraries on which it depends are static libraries.
I used this to build spatialite and sqlite for android :
https://github.com/geopaparazzi/libjsqlite-spatialite-android/wiki/spatialite-5.0.0.mk .

My makefile for the module looks like this :

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libosm_to_spatialite

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
 $(SQLITE_PATH) \
 $(SPATIALITE_PATH) \
 $(SPATIALITE_PATH)/src/headers \
 $(SPATIALITE_PATH)/src/topology \
 $(XML2_PATH)/include \
 $(XML2_PATH)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
 spatialite_osm_overpass.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
    libxml2 \
    sqlite \
    spatialite
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The build stops because none of the included header files are found in `spatialite_osm_overpass.c`.

`"spatialite_osm_overpass.c:40:10: fatal error: 'sqlite3.h' file not found"`

I added in this sqlite.mk and spatialite.mk but it does not change anything:

`LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(SQLITE_PATH)`
`LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(SPATIALITE_PATH)/src/headers`

I have tried to add
`APP_MODULES :=  sqlite spatialite xml2` in my Application.mk
but it doesn't work.

I have also tried to build this library as a static library by setting `APP_MODULES := osm_to_spatialite` but the .a is not generated.

can somebody check if my code is correct ?
alternatively, how can i generate a .a to link with JNI ?